# Svelte export variable under different name

Tags: svelte

How can I export a svelte variable under a different name? This is my current approach, having a variable named `selectedAccount` which should be exported as `value`:

```
<script>
    let selectedAccount;
    export let value;
    $: value = selectedAccount;
</script>
```

But this seems kind of bloated. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any export statement, you can export as:

```
<script>
    let selectedAccount;

    export { selectedAccount as value };
</script>
```

Example: https://svelte.dev/repl/8a925f8d32454bf595e6c81654a7d890?version=3.47.0

Comment: Wonderful thank you very much, sometimes it can be so easy.